# How do I store the date from a tkinter calendar in a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have the following work in progress code where I am trying to have a user input a date from a calendar, but I am very new to using tkinter,tkcalendar so I am not sure how to get the input to store as a variable that I can pass along to use elsewhere:

```py
def addGameTimeInfo():
    #week_number = input('Enter the week number of this game:')
    #game_date = input('Enter the date for this game(YYYY/MM/DD):')
    #season_number = input('Enter Season Number for this game:')
    def calendar_view():
        def print_sel():
            print(cal.selection_get())

        top = Toplevel(root)

        cal = Calendar(top,
                       font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                       cursor="hand1")
        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()
    def dateentry_view():
        def print_sel(e):
            print(cal.get_date())
        top = Toplevel(root)
        
        ttk.Label(top, text = 'Choose date').pack(padx=10,pady=10)
        cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background = 'darkblue',
                       foreground ='white',borderwidth=2)
        cal.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
        cal.bind('<<DateEntrySelected>>',print_sel)
    
    root = Tk()
    s = ttk.Style(root)
    s.theme_use('clam')
    
    ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calendar',command=calendar_view).pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    ttk.Button(root,text='DateEntry',command=dateentry_view).pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

I saw this being discussed in another post but I can not comment as I am a new user, otherwise I would have posted there. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I forgot to say that when I tried to return cal and do cal.get_date() I would get the error: invalid command name ".!dateentry". I am wondering, why don't I get that error when this is called inside the function?

Comment: You can just assign a variable to the return value of `cal.get_date()`: `date = cal.get_date()`. Did you have any trouble with that?